# Using regex to parse/reduce text file

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

**edit**
I've realized I made a mistake when explaining myself. Apologies for that.

Most of the artifacts come from this path:

```
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\
```

then breaks into Artifact folders and its sub-folders like this:

```
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder\Artifact\Artifact-1.0\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder\Artifact\Artifact-1.1\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder\Artifact\Artifact-1.2\data.xxx
```

I would appreciate help with following thing:

I have this list (around 5k rows) of paths to different artifacts and they have different versions, to give you an example:

```
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder\Artifact\Artifact-1.0\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder\Artifact\Artifact-1.1\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder\Artifact\Artifact-1.2\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder2\Artifact\Artifact-1.1\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder2\Artifact\Artifact-1.2\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder2\Artifact\Artifact-1.3\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder3\Artifact\Artifact-1.2\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder3\Artifact\Artifact-1.3\data.xxx
```

And my goal to achieve is this:

```
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder\Artifact\Artifact-1.0\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder2\Artifact\Artifact-1.1\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder3\Artifact\Artifact-1.2\data.xxx
```

Basically to scope it down to just 1 version.

I've tried using `^(.*)(\n\1)+$` and `$1.` but that obviously didn't work. So I was wondering if you have an idea how to approach this. Greatly appreciate help, thanks!

Comment: Does it mean you have duplicated line pairs with a different number at the end (followed with ``\``)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct Wiktor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another attempt, see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/K5PWmE/1).

The basic idea is to isolate `someText-\d?.` in capture group 2.

Then look for `$2` in following lines.  What precedes `$2` or follows `$2` in those following lines can vary.

Find: `^(.*\\(?=.*\\))(.*-\d+\.)(.*\\?.*)(\n.*\2.*)*`
Replace: `$1$2$3`

So here is the most interesting part: `^(.*\\(?=.*\\))(.*-\d+\.)`

This will get your `Artifact-1.` or `Artifact-17.` or `someText-2.` into capture group 2.  Because using a positive lookahead `(?=.*\\)` the following group 2 `(.*-\d+\.)` will be in the last directory only.  And then `(.*\\?.*)` gathers the rest of that line into group 3.

Finally `(\n.*\2.*)*` checks to see if there is a backreference to group 2, `\2`, in any following lines.  [Technically, that backreference could be anywhere in a line, even the beginning, that can be fixed if necessary - let me know if you need that for your data.  See [safer regex101 demo if 'someText-/d.' could appear anywhere and should be ignored if not last directory](https://regex101.com/r/lNzEw0/1) and use that find.]

Comment: This is perfect Mark, thank you! If you want, you can send over the other version with backreference just to see difference but this is it :)

Comment: You can see what I meant in https://regex101.com/r/nSoLFl/1.  Where if you just had `artifact-1.1\data.xxx`  in a line without the preceding path info for example or not in the last directory, and didn't want to do anything to such a line.  Then the find regex is a little more complicated.

Comment: great, I will stick with the first option you gave me. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Find what: ^(.*\.)(\d+)\\[^\\\n]+(\n\1\d+\\[^\\\n]+)+$
  Replace: $1$2\\
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V304P0/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (it is the default  `^` behavior in Visual Studio Code)
- `(.*\.)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `.`
- `(\d+)` - Group 2:
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `[^\\\n]+` - one or more chars other than `\` and a line break
- `(\n\1\d+\\[^\\\n]+)+` - Group 3 capturing one or more sequences of a line break and then the value captured into Group 1, one or more digits, a `\` char and then one or more chars other than `\` and a line break
- `$` - end of a line.

Comment: Wiktor, I've tested out code you provided however it seems to not work. It might be related to my fault and that is most of the content is on this path `D:\Folder\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\`  then it breaks into subfolders and just then into artifacts so the path looks like this `D:\Folder\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Artifact\Artifact-1.0`  however it might have more subfolders before it leads to artifact. Hope I explained myself correctly now.

Comment: @crNh Sorry, that is not clear, you need to update the question.

Comment: just done that, sorry.

Comment: @crNh That's fine, see my update.

Comment: A small change to Wiktor's example seems to be what you want: see https://regex101.com/r/BKTY9u/1

Comment: @Wiktor it doesn't seem to find what I need though with updated information

Comment: @Mark yes, that is actually close to what I need. However I see that ArtifactFolder2 has 2 version folders and I would need to cut it down just to one.

Comment: @crNh See https://regex101.com/r/V304P0/1, doesn't it do what you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't understand why, but when I do search it won't find a single line - just gives me no results..

Comment: @crNh Did you select the regex mode? A dot with asterisk option?

Comment: @crNh Add a screenshot to the question, with your exact settings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mark already provided me with what I needed (see below please) and yes, regex was selected. However I really appreciate your help and effort put into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a single capture group for the whole line using `^(.*)`, as you want to repeat only the part before the last dot using a backreference and that will not work capturing the whole line.

Therefore you have to capture the digits in the first match in a separate capture group to keep it in the replacement.

If you want to match all following lines with the same text before the last dot, you can use a repeating group:

```
^\s*(.*\.)(\d+\\[^\\\r\n]*)(?:\r?\n\s*\1\d*\\[^\\\r\n]*)+
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(.*\.)` Capture **group 1**, match till the last dot
- `(\d+\\[^\\\r\n]*)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits, `\` and optional chars other than `\` or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n\s*\1` Match a newline and a backreference to group 1
  - `\d+\\[^\\\r\n]*` Same pattern as in the first part
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jRzBgY/1).

In the replacement use the 2 capture groups `$1$2`

The replacement will look like

```
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder\Artifact\Artifact-1.0\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder2\Artifact\Artifact-1.1\data.xxx
D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\ArtifactFolder3\Artifact\Artifact-1.2\data.xxx
```

Comment: sorry, wasn't on point with my explanation. Updated my question, please check it again.

Comment: @crNh Do you mean that there can be more chars other than `\\` after it like this? https://regex101.com/r/OmMwGg/1

Comment: updated it once again, to make it crystal clear. But yes that's it.

Comment: @crNh Like this `^\s*(.*\.)(\d+)(\\[^\\\r\n]*)(?:\n\1\d+\\[^\\\r\n]*)+` https://regex101.com/r/7G0pqG/1

Comment: @crNh Should the `\data.xxx` also be the same for all parts? Or only the part before the last dot?

Comment: that actually looks very promising! Though the `\data.xxx` was just to show there are some data inside folders and they are different from exe to xml, bin and pom files. If that answers your question.

Comment: @crNh Ok I have updated the pattern to match optional chars after the last backslash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243528/discussion-between-crnh-and-the-fourth-bird).